# Harvesting and preview is successful but download is failing

Tags: ckan

We've turned on harvesting and a preview is working great but I cannot download a dataset.

I'm getting this:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

and a "Server internal error" on a website. If you need any more info or logs, feel free to ask! Thank you!

Also, I'm using the DGU package.

More logs:

- 2017-04-26 12:55:36,100 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables defined in memory
- 2017-04-26 12:55:36,111 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables already exist
- 2017-04-26 12:55:36,129 DEBUG [ckanext.harvest.model] Harvest tables defined in memory
- 2017-04-26 12:55:36,134 DEBUG [ckanext.harvest.model] Harvest tables already exist
- 2017-04-26 12:55:36,390 CRITI [ckan.lib.uploader] Please specify a ckan.storage_path in your config for your uploads

Comment: Logs showing the exception traceback please. For DGU it is probably: /var/log/ckan/ckan-apache.error.log

Answer (score 0):

You must set up  `ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan/default` variable in your .ini file